# Automation of Excel activity on SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vsto

Here is what I need to happen, without a single user action:

1. Data resides in a CSV file on a SharePoint directory.
2. SharePoint then loads the data file into excel and refreshes pivot tables.
3. SharePoint then copies the newly updated file to another folder on SharePoint for users.

I understand I need to be using VSTO code, but I can't figure out it what I am asking for is possible.

I can't have a user perform any of the steps in this workflow, it needs to be automated. Please assume the updated data file will be updated automatically. I appreciate all your suggestions and maybe your solution will end up in our company, Coke. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved this with writing a C# console application. It opened excel ran the scripts and then saved the file to a tmp directory. From there I iterated through the temp directory and placed the files on the Sharepoint server.